# Sound looping all the time

Tags: ios, ipad, audio, cocos2d-iphone

I have implemented to methods that loads me array of sounds:

```
-(void) soundSuper
{
    [soundEngine stopAllSounds];

    [soundEngine playSound:(1000+tag) sourceGroupId:1 pitch:1 pan:1 gain:1.0f loop:NO];
    NSLog(@"sound1 activated");

    [self schedule:@selector(playSecondSound) interval:2];
}

-(void) playSecondSound {
    [self unschedule:@selector(playSecondSound)];
    [soundEngine playSound:(1008+tag) sourceGroupId:1 pitch:1 pan:1 gain:1.0f loop:NO];
    NSLog(@"sound2 activated");
}
```

here, it loads the sound and then is played when touching a button. The 2 sounds, at the same moment.
The thing is that now, I want to load the sound in my initScene. I am getting this with this method:

```
[self schedule:@selector(soundSuper) interval:2];
```

but the problem is that when I enter, the sound is played, but it loops all the time. I don't know what to do, because I have unshedule it on the void second sound method. Is something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont you think you should unschedule the "soundSuper" selector also, like this

```
-(void) soundSuper
{
    //HERE : you unschedule this selector too.
    [self unschedule:@selector(soundSuper)];

    [soundEngine stopAllSounds];

    [soundEngine playSound:(1000+tag) sourceGroupId:1 pitch:1 pan:1 gain:1.0f loop:NO];
    NSLog(@"sound1 activated");

    [self schedule:@selector(playSecondSound) interval:2];
}
```